# How to use CollectionType with FosRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm building an API with the FOSRestBundle and I'm trying to add existing `Employee` entities to an existing `Report` entity. But my form validation keeps throwing an error: `This form should not contain extra fields`

Adding `'allow_add' => true` to the ReportType options is not an option because I only want to add excisting employees to the Report. How can I make this work?

**PUT request body**

```
{  
    "report":{  
        "notes":"This is a note.",
        "client":5,
        "contactPerson":4,
        "contributors":[
            {
                "id": 10
            }
        ]
   }
}
```

**ReportType**

```
class ReportType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('notes')
            ->add('client', 'entity', array(
               'class' => 'ApiBundle:Client'
            ))
            ->add('contactPerson', 'entity', array(
               'class' => 'ApiBundle:ContactPerson'
            ))
            ->add('contributors', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'   => EmployeeType::class,
                'by_reference' => false
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ApiBundle\Entity\Report',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

**Snippet from Report entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ApiBundle\Entity\Employee", inversedBy="contributions", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="reports_contributors")
 */
private $contributors;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->contributors = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add contributor
 *
 * @param \ApiBundle\Entity\Employee $contributor
 *
 * @return Report
 */
public function addContributor(\ApiBundle\Entity\Employee $contributor)
{
    $this->contributors[] = $contributor;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove contributor
 *
 * @param \ApiBundle\Entity\Employee $contributor
 */
public function removeContributor(\ApiBundle\Entity\Employee $contributor)
{
    $this->contributors->removeElement($contributor);
}

/**
 * Get contributors
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getContributors()
{
    return $this->contributors;
}
```

**Snippet from Employee Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ApiBundle\Entity\Report", mappedBy="contributors")
 */
private $contributions;

public function __construct() {
    $this->contributions = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add contribution
 *
 * @param \ApiBundle\Entity\Report $contribution
 *
 * @return Employee
 */
public function addContribution(\ApiBundle\Entity\Report $contribution)
{
    $this->contributions[] = $contribution;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove contribution
 *
 * @param \ApiBundle\Entity\Report $contribution
 */
public function removeContribution(\ApiBundle\Entity\Report $contribution)
{
    $this->contributions->removeElement($contribution);
}

/**
 * Get contributions
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getContributions()
{
    return $this->contributions;
}
```

## Solved it!

No need to use `CollectionType`. The solution is to use an `EntityType` with the `multiple` option.

```
->add('contributors', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'ApiBundle:Employee',
    'multiple' => true
))
```

**PUT request body**

```
{  
   "report":{  
        "notes":"This is a note.",
        "client":5,
        "contactPerson":4,
        "contributors":[10,6]
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're not getting that error because of the root level "report" on your JSON? Could you also show your Form instantiation in the controller?

Comment: No, the form works perfectly without the "contributors" field.